# Is Nhibernate 5.2.6 compatible with .netcore 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-core, nhibernate, asp.net-core-mvc

we are trying to migrate to .net-core 3.0 from .net-core 2.2, is nhibernate fully compatible with .netcore 3.0 ?

Currently, we are using .netcore 2.2 and nhibernate is fully compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know Nhibernate 5.2.3 is full compatible with .net core 3.0.
It seems Nhibernate 5.2.6 is same as 5.2.6.

https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-nhibernate/

BR